# PostgreSql : Adding a point to an existing polygon

Tags: postgresql, polygons

I can't seem to find the right resources on how to do this in postgres.

I know how to create a new polygon

```
insert into polygon_table values (1, '((2,2),(3,4),(3,6))');
```

and say I want to **add the point (1,1)** to the existing polygon.

If I have a column of polygon type with an existing polygon let's say 3 points (which makes a triangle) and I want to update the polygon to add another point to make it rectangular.

How do I do this in Postgres?

Comment: Someone may give you a query to do this, but I would recommend that you change your table design to _not_ store all points in CSV format.  Instead, let each point be a separate record.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why not rather store it as a polygon, since it is a polygon? Putting all points in a separate table would make things much more complicated. The column is not a string in this case.

Comment: yes i really meant to store it as polygon type, so I wouldn't need to run an additional join when querying the polygon as I intend to retrieve 50 + polygons in a single load and plot it in Google maps.

Comment: @muffin Would it be possible to rather use PostGIS data types? Then it should be quite trivial to handle this, but with the built-in polygon type it seems to be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Facepalm.  I had no idea such a type even existed.  Bad on me.  I'm on a cell phone right now.

Comment: I agree with Sami: if you need to do this a lot (manipulate polygons) then using PostGIS is probably the easiest solution

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen.. i've heard about PostGIS but I've got no idea what it is. Is it an extension that's readily installable? like a plugin or something like that? or is it an entirely new DB? thanks

Comment: @muffin It's an easy-to-install extension of geographical functions for PostgreSQL. It can do basically anything you can imagine and this case would be quite simple since you can convert the polygon to a linestring, add a point and convert back (if needed). You can split, concatenate, check intersections, convert to this and that, have holes in polygons etc. http://postgis.net/